# Android: using LocationManager and provider

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am new to android and was trying out stuff on my android emulator. While playing with the location manager and location listener, I could test the code of changing location using the emulator. The locationlistener catches the location change and moves to the specific location.

I now want to replicate the same test using my program, i.e. pass new coordinates every x seconds (may be through a thread ?) to the locationlistener, but through my program and not the emulator.

Can someone please suggest a way to go about implementing this functionality ?

The code for location listener that I found somewhere on the net and was trying:

---

```
private LocationListener locationListener;

private MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps); 

    lm = (LocationManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mpview);
    mc = mapView.getController();

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}        

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location locn) {
        if (locn != null) {                
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (locn.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (locn.getLongitude() * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(point);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
        Bundle extras) {

    }
}
```

---

Thanks!